# Change part of CSS3 linear-gradient from codebehind

Tags: asp.net, html, css

Is there a way to change part of a CSS3 linear-gradient from codebehind? e.g.:

In Site.css:

```
.MyClass{ background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #FFFFFF, #000000); }
```

And in the markup:

```
<div class="MyClass">Stuff</div>
```

I want to change (from codebehind) the `#000000` only. And only for that div.

Comment: Where does the style .MyClass come from?

Comment: So .MyClass is a style you have on the page itself, not in a style sheet?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev No. In Site.css.

Comment: @Neps It's a class I have in Site.css.

Comment: Then your options are to either a) generate Site.css from code behind, or b) change class or inline style from code behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
<style>
    .MyClass{ background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #FFFFFF, <%=myVariable%>); }
</style>
```

In your master page, in the HEAD.

You should leave your stylesheet as-is before this (inline stylesheet). This allows the browser to continue to cache your main CSS file.

Comment: The class is in a stylesheet and is used by several pages.

Comment: Then use a different class name, or insert this on only the page that needs it. Alternately you can set the target style at run-time using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Since your styles are in a style sheet, you should create a new class, then you can set the class of that div from the code behind.

Page:

```
<div id="_myClass" runat="server">Stuff</div>
```

Code

```
_myClass.Attributes["class"] = "MyNewClass";
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to make a new class, you can override it from code behind, but this would be messy if you make the gradient cross browser compliant, plus it'd be a pain to update if you change colors again... so isn't recommended:

```
 _myClass.Attributes["style"] = "background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #FFFFFF, #CCCCCC);";
```